# Let Text (X Axis) Overflow A Y Axis Scroll

Tags: html, css

Currently  have a div that has a height of 1000px, and if it goes higher then 1000px it has a overflow:scroll. Now I have parts of that div that when hovered pop up information that overflows to the Y axis (SHOULD go over the scroll bar). Yet the overflowing information just stops at the scroll bar, and it should go OVER the scroll bar. I have even set z-indexs, but the overflowing text will not pass over the scroll bar. How could I fix this? Thank You! :)

**EDIT**

I have tried much more on trying to fix this. When I remove overflow-y: scroll, it then flows out of the div (which is good). Yet when I add the overflow-y: scroll the scroll bar stops text from passing it. So I do not know why this scroll bar is messing everything up.

Comment: have you tried setting position:absolute to the pop-ups?

Comment: Yep, they still will not flow over the scroll bars on the Y axis.

Answer (score 0):

mm, works perfectly fine hen i try it, here's my test-code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .window{
                height:300px;
                width:500px;
                overflow:scroll;
            }
            .popup{
                position:absolute;
                height:500px;
                border:red solid 2px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="window">
        <span class="popup">asdasd</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Numerous testing and it will still not work :( Please look at the update.

Comment: hmm, what a mess, waht browser are you using ?

Comment: Hmm its ok, I found another way to do what I want :)